# can't intent to UserAreaActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm trying to do an intent like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
```

the problem is android studio tell me that cannot resolve symbol UserAreaActivity

my UserAreaActivity.class:

```
public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerView.OnScrollChangeListener {
```

what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Import your `UserAreaActivity` into `LoginActivity`.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a LoginActivity.java and use this Intent code in that LoginActivity.java

I hope this helps !

Comment: I'm using this in LoginActivity.java. And I have UserAreaActivity.java the error is in UserAreaActivity.class, if I don't use the extends and implements it works, but I need to use extend and implement...

Comment: I think you are more concerned in using a class in another class which in this case means LoginActivity in UserAreaActivity is it so?

Comment: I need to open UserAreaActivity after user Login. So I'm trying to do an intent for this. The problem is the UserAreaActivity is not found, I think that is because the extends or implements, because if I remove this, the intent will work...

Comment: Wait a minute you can give a try to Sync project with gradle or either cleaning your project

Answer (score 1):

Did you import your `UserAreaActivity` in your `LoginActivity` with
`import com.example.MyFirstApp.UserAreaActivity`?

If so:
Are you sure that you defined `public class UserAreaActivity...` instead of `private class UserAreaActivity...`?

And btw: You don't have to do `LoginActivity.this`. A simple `this` is enough.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I need to open UserAreaActivity after user Login. So I'm trying to do an intent for this. The problem is the UserAreaActivity is not found, I think that is because the extends or implements, because if I remove this, the intent will work...

Comment: are both classes in the same package? or is one in a subpackage?

Comment: in the same package

Comment: acually, it doesn't make a lot of sense... Did you already tried to Clean, and rebuild your project?

Comment: you can do that via Tools -> Clean Project and Tools -> Rebuild Project

Comment: it works now, package name was wrong. sorry for take your time!

Comment: ok. great. would be nice from you to set this as an accepted awnser, so others see that this question is answered :)